# Obtaining type information with Template Haskell

Tags: haskell, template-haskell, type-level-computation

I'm currently working on a library that allows the user to specify a list of *command specifications* as follows:

```hs
data CommandDef = forall (as :: [*]). Typeable as => CommandDef {
  argTypes :: Proxy as,
  commandName :: String,
  commandStrings :: [String],
  parsers :: HList (FMap CommandParser as),
  description :: Maybe String
}
```

This list of command specifications can then be passed into a template haskell function `genCommands :: [CommandDef] -> Q [Dec]` to generate a `Command` data type representing the different types of commands that the user has specified, together with a function `parseCommands :: String -> Maybe Command`, where `argTypes` specifies the types of the command's arguments to be parsed, and `parsers` is an HList of the relevant parsers for the given `argTypes`.

The issue is, I need to somehow get a `Type` (from Language.Haskell.TH) for each of the `argTypes` in a `CommandDef` in order to properly generate the `Command` type with Template Haskell -- while still keeping the type safety of making sure all of the `parsers` are of the appropriate type. (The idea is, if `commandName = "CommandName` and `argTypes = Proxy @'[ArgType1, ArgType2]`, a constructor of form `CommandName ArgType1 ArgType2` will be generated in the `Command` type.)

So, really, in an ideal world, what I would like is a function `Proxy as -> Q [Type]`, or something similar, but I'm not sure if this is possible to do in Template Haskell.

Is there such a thing? Or is there any way my approach could be modified in order to accomplish all of the same goals with Template Haskell?

I have considered adding a redundant field `argTypesTH :: [Name]` which contains all of the names of the types in `argTypes`, but I'm not even sure how this could work, because I can't seem to find a template haskell function which takes a type name, and returns the needed `Type` that needs to be specified for the constructors of my `Command` type. (There is `reifyType`, but I'm not sure if that can do what I want, as that takes the name of a value and returns a type)

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to go from `*` to a template haskell `Type`.  I think you will need to include the `Type` in `CommandDef` somehow.

Comment: Can you do TH when the `CommandDef`s get made? Would `let ty = [t| '[ArgType1, ArgType2] ] in CommandDef{ argTypes = Proxy @($ty), argTypesTH = ty }` work?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica: Possibly, I will try that.

Comment: I'm not sure how to handle the fact that [t| ... |] returns a `Q Type` rather than a `Type`. I guess I could make `genCommands` take a `Q [CommandDef]` as argument.

Comment: Since my solution doesn't use `reify`, if you have `IO` handy, you could always `runQ` it.